# Stop Non-Ajax File Upload on Form Submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a form which includes a bunch of text and date fields as well as a "file" input (see below)

```
<button class="contact100-form-upload-btn" id="uploadbutton" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('uploadedfile').click()">Upload Picture Identification </button>
<input style="display:none" name="uploadedfile" id="uploadedfile" onchange="selectfile()" type="file" accept="image/*" />

        function selectfile() {
      var x = document.getElementById("progdiv");
      x.style.display = "block";
     var file = _("uploadedfile").files[0];
     //alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+" | "+file.type);
     var formdata = new FormData();
     formdata.append("uploadedfile", file);
     var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
     ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
     ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
     ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
     ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
     ajax.open("POST", "file_upload_parser.php?confnum=" + <?php echo $confnum ?> + "&file=1"); 
     ajax.send(formdata);
     
     formData.delete(uploadedfile);
     
     document.getElementById("uploadbutton").style.backgroundColor = "#FF5733";
     document.getElementById("uploadbutton").innerHTML = "Photo Uploading";
    }
```

The selectfile() function is a nice file upload function using Ajax which shows a little upload status bar so the user knows what's going on. All of this functionality works perfectly and the file uploads to the sever. The issue is when I submit the form, the file get's uploaded again which sort of defeats the purpose of uploading it with Ajax. Is there a way to make an input field (file) not be part of a form, or delete the file element from the from altogether (as it has already been uploaded) before submitting it? Or maybe another way I am totally missing?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

-Lawrence

Comment: Maybe you can try preventing the default behaviour with **event.preventDefault()** on listening to `file input` click

Comment: update your `selectFile()` function here for more clarity.

Comment: @sidverma Done!

Comment: Actually I think I got it. Removing the "enctype="multipart/form-data".from the form type seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to remove multipart/form-data from the form so it ignores file uploads.

"When you are writing client-side code:
use multipart/form-data when your form includes any  elements
otherwise you can use multipart/form-data or application/x-www-form-urlencoded but application/x-www-form-urlencoded will be more efficient"

This solution will obviously not work if you want to upload some files but solved my issue.